# C can't correctly clean stdin

Tags: c, stdin

[image]I'm having a strange problem.
I'm creating a chatroom. I use **fgets()** to get the characters i write to stdin.
Thing is: i want to flush the stdin before i start using fgets. That's because i could have written things on the stdin before the thread who sends the messages started.
If I don't flush the stdin, i could write '1','2,'3' on the terminal, then i connect to someone, and the fgets takes from the stdin this ''garbage'' i previously wrote.
I'm using this function to clear the stdin:

```
void clear_stdin() {
  int c;
  do {
    c = getchar();
  }   while (c != EOF && c != '\n');
}
```

But this doesn't work as it should: if i write on the terminal numbers from 1 to 9, it ''clears'' just the even numbers, so it sends 1,3,5,7,9.
It's a strange behaviour, but the idea is correct. It's clearing the buffer, but not totally. It jumps some characters.
How can i solve this?

This is the function that use it:

```
void send_msg_handler() {
  // Questa funzione và passata al thread che gestisce l'invio dei messaggi.

    char message[LENGTH_MSG] = {};
    while (1) {
      clear_stdin();
        overwrite_stdout();
        while (fgets(message, LENGTH_MSG, stdin) != NULL) {
            string_trim(message, LENGTH_MSG);
            if (strlen(message) == 0) {
                overwrite_stdout();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        send(sockfd, message, LENGTH_MSG, 0);
        if (strcmp(message, "exit") == 0) {
          exit_from_client(1);
        } else if (strcmp(message, "menu") == 0){
          back_to_menu(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Why is there a `putchar` in that loop?

Comment: There should be _no_ need to "clear" `stdin`. `fgets` is _atomic_. It either gets a full line or it doesn't (e.g. EOF). So, a given thread (assuming multiple threads try to read `stdin`) will get a whole line. That's because stdio streams have a thread lock that guarantees the atomic access. BTW, your clear code has a bug: It checks for EOF _after_ doing `putchar`.

Comment: And if there *wasn't* anything in the input buffer, the function will block until there is, and clear the input meant for `fgets()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane do you have any ideas?

Comment: Issue a prompt to press Enter to begin. Then clear the input. But with Windows I could use `kbhit()` and `getch()` to dispose of anything. In Linux you can use termios to test for and read unbuffered input (not reliant on Enter pressed).

Comment: What are the definitions of `overwrite_stdout` and `string_trim`? Again, please post a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise we're just left to speculate.